# Why doesn't this buffered channel block in my code?

Tags: go

I'm learning the Go language. Can someone please explain the output here?

```
package main

import "fmt"

var c = make(chan int, 1)

func f() {

    c <- 1

    fmt.Println("In f()")
}

func main() {
    go f()

    c <- 2
    fmt.Println(<-c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)

}
```

Output:

```
In f()
2
1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why did "In f()" occur before "2"? If "In f()" is printed before "2", the buffered channel should block. But this didn't happen, why?

The other outputs are reasonable.

[Image of my confusing result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXET3.png)

Comment: This does not match my observations: it prints `2, In f(), 1` for me. However, if I add a delay after `go f()` it results in a deadlock, as expected.

Comment: Also https://play.golang.org/p/9a5yrQugckg

Comment: it is not blocked fmt.Println(<-c) occasionally happened before f() in separate goroutine and you gave buffer 1 to channel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of events that cause this to run through are these:

1. Trigger goroutine.
2. Write `2` to the channel. Capacity of the channel is now exhausted.
3. Read from the channel and output result.
4. Write `1` to the channel.
5. Read from the channel and output result.

The order of events that cause this to deadlock are these:

1. Trigger goroutine.
2. Write `1` to the channel. Capacity of the channel is now exhausted.
3. Write `2` to the channel. Since the channel's buffer is full, this blocks.

The output you provide seems to indicate that the goroutine finishes first and the program doesn't deadlock, which contradicts above two scenarios as explanation. Here's what happens though:

1. Trigger goroutine.
2. Write `2` to the channel.
3. Read `2` from the channel.
4. Write `1` to the channel.
5. Output `In f()`.
6. Output the `2` received from the channel.
7. Read `1` from the channel.
8. Output the `1` received from the channel.

Keep in mind that you don't have any guarantees concerning the scheduling of goroutines unless you programmatically enforce them. When you start a goroutine, it is undefined when the first code of that goroutine are actually executed and how much the starting code progresses until then. Note that since your code relies on a certain order of events, it is broken by that definition, just to say that explicitly.

Also, at any point in your program, the scheduler can decide to switch between different goroutines. Even the single line `fmt.Printtln(<-c)` consists of multiple steps and in between each step the switch can occur.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think the roder in f() are:
1. Write 1 to the channel. Capacity of the channel is now exhausted.
2. Print "In f()".
 
  As my output shows, i firstly get "In f()".  At this case, i think "1" has been written to the channel and the channel is exhausted. Then the ouput shows "2" but how can i write 2 to the channel when it is exhausted. I can't think of a situation when "In f()" is printed before "2".

Comment: Okay, I'll try to clarify this.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I get it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To reproduce block you have to run that code many times the easiest way to do it with test. You don't have block cause of luck. But it is not guaranteed:

```
var c = make(chan int, 1)

func f() {

    c <- 1

    fmt.Println("In f()")
}

func TestF(t *testing.T) {
    go f()

    c <- 2
    fmt.Println(<-c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)

}
```

and run with command:

```
go test -race -count=1000 -run=TestF -timeout=4s
```

where `count` number of tests. It reproduces blocking to me.
Provide timeout to not wait default 10 minutes